# use component as a validation error message

Tags: laravel-8

Laravel 8

I'm trying to replace the duplicated validation error message by a component

Register.blade.php:

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
     <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    <x-alert :input="email" />
  </div>
```

Alert.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Alert extends Component
{
  public $input;

  public function __construct($input)
  {
    $this->input = $input;
  }


  public function render()
  {
    return view('components.alert');
  }
}
```

alert.blade.php:

```
@error($input)
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

but it gives me an error

> Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' (this will throw an
> Error in a future version of PHP) (View:
> C:\laragon\www\practice\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it as following

```php
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
   <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}">    
   <x-alert input="email" />
</div>
```

the `:` symbole makes it resolve as PHP code not literal string